# Update a pandas DataFrame with iloc from another Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Long story short : I've got a DataFrame like this template :

```
         city  Longitude   Latitude
0     Gotham City  35.699708   2.158089
1         Xibalba  35.676700   4.199400
2        Eldorado  35.680871   6.165926
3        Atlantis  35.680339   8.165897
4         Elysium  35.678219  10.165940
5  Lost City of Z  35.678037  12.166077
6       Parnasius  35.678192  14.165853
```

And I used an algorithm to solve the Traveling Salesman Problem. My solution is a list, like this :

```
sorting_order = [4,5,2,1,0,6,3]
```

To be clear, df.iloc[4] should be in first position, then df.iloc[5], df.iloc[2], etc... So I created a new empty DF :

```
df_sorted = pd.DataFrame(columns =['city','Longitude','Latitude'])
```

And finally, I tried this simple for loop to update df_sorted in the right oder :

```
for index in sorting_order:
    df_sorted.append(df.iloc[index])
```

But df_sorted remains empty at the end of the loop... Could I update a new DF using the iloc of an other or not ?

Comment: Is `iloc` really more appropriate than `loc` here? I only see disadvantages to the former and advantages to the latter.

Comment: I  think I see what you mean, but result is the same after a reset_index... No ?

Comment: I’m concerned about the appropriate use of `loc` and `iloc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already mention `iloc`, why don't you try:

```
df.iloc[sorting_order]
```

Output:

```
             city  Longitude   Latitude
4         Elysium  35.678219  10.165940
5  Lost City of Z  35.678037  12.166077
2        Eldorado  35.680871   6.165926
1         Xibalba  35.676700   4.199400
0     Gotham City  35.699708   2.158089
6       Parnasius  35.678192  14.165853
3        Atlantis  35.680339   8.165897
```

Comment: taking advantage of the exact knowledge of the methods

Answer (score 1):

Just re-index the dataframe, then reset the index.

```
>>> df.reindex(sorting_order).reset_index(drop=True)
             city  Longitude   Latitude
0         Elysium  35.678219  10.165940
1  Lost_City_of_Z  35.678037  12.166077
2        Eldorado  35.680871   6.165926
3         Xibalba  35.676700   4.199400
4     Gotham_City  35.699708   2.158089
5       Parnasius  35.678192  14.165853
6        Atlantis  35.680339   8.165897
```